# IntelliJ problem tab not showing live issues - problems tree does

Tags: intellij-idea

we are using IntelliJ 2018.2 and we just migrated from Eclipse and we have some issues with the error views in IntelliJ.

We activated "Make project automatically" and now we can see new errors in the "Problems" - tree view on the left side even without saving the file (that works great). But we can not see how many errors exist within the file and there are no details about the error.

[image]

Now we tried the bottom "Problems" - tab instead of the tree because we do need the project view on the left side to navigate.

The bottom "Problems" tab does not show any errors at all until we hit "Build project". Just saving a file does not show any errors.

[image]

Why is this behaviour as it is? Is there an option to move the problems tree to the bottom area and let the project view on the left side as it is right now?

Thanks
Hauke

Comment: have you configure your jdk for the project ? (because it must appear as  a lib)

Comment: Make sure automatic compilation works. Note that it's suspended when any run configuration is active. I [cannot reproduce this problem](https://i.imgur.com/kJid1cq.png). Please [contact support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new) for further assistance.

Comment: Yes the JDK 8 is visible unter "external libraries" -> <1.8> - c:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_131